# How to concat two Strings with different textAppearance in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-widget, spanned

Now I have this code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
String html = name + " - <small>" + description + "</small>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

Where textView has `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`. But what I need is instance of `<small>` put the textApparence `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, I dont understand your purpose but why don't you use the `setTextAppearance(context, resId)` method directly in your code to change the text appearance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know to use tag `<small>`, but you can use this to override style for part of text:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append("name - ");
int start = sb.length();
sb.append("description");
sb.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small), start, sb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.append(" - ");
myText.setText(sb);
```